# jax-ws webservice client returns only empty objects

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I generate a Web Service Client with the assistant of Eclipse passing the WSDL of the provider Web Service.

I generate in a JUnit test case the object to pass to the Web Service.

```
//After set properties of the request object
AbacusWebService wsAbacus = new AbacusWebService();
WebServiceResult wsResult = wsAbacus.irsValoration(requestObject);
```

With the monitor TCP-IP of Eclipse I see the the request and the response and both are correct. The response returns data:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
  <irsValorationResponse xmlns="http://webServices.isban.es">
    <irsValorationReturn>
      <error xsi:nil="true"/>
      <format>dd/MM/yyyy</format>
      <pricingDate>02/09/2012</pricingDate>
      <results>
        <results>
          <bpv>-492.6493116525817</bpv>
          <cer xsi:nil="true"/>
          <chargeRunning xsi:nil="true"/>
          <chargeUpfront xsi:nil="true"/>
          <error xsi:nil="true"/>
          <gamma>0.004649336915463209</gamma>
          <gammaTotal xsi:nil="true"/>
          <minCerReturn xsi:nil="true"/>
          <name>IRS</name>
          <npv>46371.877687584296</npv>
          <payingNpv>0.0</payingNpv>
          <pricingDelta>433.0423619134596</pricingDelta>
          <receivingNpv>46371.877687584296</receivingNpv>
          <swapRate>0.9412756009346844</swapRate>
        </results>
      </results>
    </irsValorationReturn>
  </irsValorationResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

But when I inspect the response object (wsResult), all of their properties are null.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you getting if you try with [SopaUI](http://www.soapui.org/)?

Comment: Same response I wrote above. Soap request and response generated by Web Service client are correct. I copy/paste the request from TCP-IP Monitor to Soap UI and the response is the same

Comment: The same happens if you create the webservice client with the [wsimport](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/) tool?

Comment: Yes, the same happens, I think the problem is the namespace